# cant select spesific rows and find null variables

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, data-cleaning

ın the data there are 7 devices and ı want to select 1st device which device ıd is 1. And define how many null variables in it.

i have tried this but it didnt gave me the null variables of speed

df1 = df['Device_ID']==1
df1.isnull().sum()

Comment: please provide your data as text, not images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.